# Spring Boot - Automatically Enable Hibernate Session Filter When the Transaction Starts

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-session

I would like to know if it is possible to intercept the Hibernate Session creation, to automatically enable a filter when the transaction starts. I can do this if and only if spring Boot uses a dedicated session for each http request: my second question.

I have a Service class with a method marked as `@Transactional`.

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveEntity(Entity entity) {
        //save entity
    }
}
```

I have a RestController class that exposes an endpoint and it uses the service class.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service")
public class MyRestController {
    
    private final MyService myService;
    
    @GetMapping("save")
    public String save() {
        myService.saveEntity(entity);
    }
}
```

- Does Spring Boot create a new dedicated hibernate session for the http request?
- If yes, is it possible to intercept (via callback for example) the session creation to enable an hibernate filter?